# Isotope + infiniteScroll + Wordpress + Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-4, infinite-scroll, jquery-isotope

I am trying a relatively simple thing..

I have a custom-post-type archive page in wordpress and I display ten posts per page in pagination and run **isotope js** for div packing and I use **next_posts_link()** to generate a link with id '#next_archive_page'. All good and this all works as expected.

Now I'm trying to add the jQuery which will implement the **infiniteScroll** functionality but the only way I can get the images of these new posts to render is to remove the bootstrap class of img-fluid from them ( this is simply width: 100%; height: auto; ) ...

```
<div class="row grid">
    <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ?>
    <div class="grid-sizer col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="...">
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query() ?>
</div>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {

        var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
            itemSelector : '.grid-item',
            columnWidth : '.grid-sizer',
            percentPosition : true
        });

        $grid.infiniteScroll({
            hideNav: '.pagination',
            path : '.pagination #next_archive_page',
            scrollThresold: 200
        });

        $grid.on( 'load.infiniteScroll', function( event, response, path ) {
            var $items = $( response ).find('.grid-item');
            // It's the height: auto style that stops images displaying
            $items.find('img').removeClass('img-fluid');
            $items.imagesLoaded( function() {
                $grid.append( $items );
                $grid.isotope( 'insert', $items );
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

I don't want to remove the ing-fluid class because I need it for my responsive layout...

So the result of this is that it's appending the *.grid-item* elements from the next custom-post-type archive pages in the correct place, but they are all overlapping and the wrong size.

How can I get infiniteScroll and isotope to play nice with bootstrap responsiveness?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the styling of the elements? It sounds like they are added with 0 width and/or 0 height.

Comment: Well actually, I just prodded it for a while and realised that there is a bootstrap class 'img-fluid' on the images that is causing the issue. If I take this off then the next pages images do render... But how do I solve that? Because this class is necessary for my layout.

Comment: You can overrule the bootstrap styling rules causing the issue in the elements css class.
You just have to make sure it's more specific than the bootstrap css rule.
As a last resort you could use !import on the css properties in your class, this will cause them to have maximum priority but is discouraged in most cases since it can no longer be overruled. 
If the class is already added at the point you append the element you could iterate over the elements and remove the bootstrap class in your javascript.

Comment: Yes, so I need the css as it is... But I have tried calling _$items.find('img').removeClass('img-fluid');_ within the **load.infiniteScroll** callback function which works, however, I need to put that class back before isotope shows the elements, because what I get at the moment is overlapping images being appended. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd try and find the css property in 'img-fluid' that correctly aligns them and add it to your own css.
You could also try keeping the bootstrap class and see if you can change your own css to fix with display issue.
I'd start with the display, width and height properties.